# How to use table() function for all categorical variables in a dataset?

Tags: r

I want to create a function to create table output for all  categorical variables(say v1 ,v2 ,v3 ,v4 ....) in data set -> ev_table , using table() function

```
table = data.frame(table( ev_table$v1, ev_table$target_var))
```

to avoid repeating the same code for each variable again and again...

Attempts to paste names of variables leads to error due to quotes getting carried along with the name / character value of the variable

Any help welcome.

Comment: Please do provide some example data and your expected result.  Do you need to call `table` in a pairwise manner for the categorical variables?

Comment: I did reminded you about reproducible example in your first post.

Comment: How about `lapply(df, table)` instead?

Comment: @docendodiscimus  Based on the code showed by the OP, he is using two columns.  `target_var` may be a common variable (not sure though)..

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it seems you wanted to apply the `table` function on each of the categorical variables ("V1", "V2", etc) and the common "target_var" in the dataset ("ev_table").  Here, I am creating a dataset with multiple categorical variables along with "target_var".  If your dataset also have other columns, the categorical columns needs to be subsetted.  The code below get an index of all the variables except 'target_var' (`setdiff(...)`), loop over those columns (`sapply(..)`), get the `table` between those columns and the "target_var".

```
indx <- setdiff(colnames(ev_table), 'target_var')
sapply(ev_table[indx], function(x) table(x, ev_table[,'target_var']))
```

Or

```
mapply(`table`, ev_table[indx], list(ev_table[,'target_var']))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
ev_table <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 4*20,
             replace=TRUE), ncol=4))
set.seed(29)
ev_table$target_var <- sample(LETTERS[1:6],20, replace=TRUE)
```